# IOS: Interact with element during custom transition

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'm doing a custom slide in transition on a modal view controller. 
I have a big dimiss button on the modal view, but I can't press it and dismiss the view until the transition animation is completely finished.

Is it possible to enable userInteraction on the views elements during the transition?

Thanks

Comment: How long does your custom transition take? I would suggest looking into making it quick enough that it doesn't matter whether or not you can interact while it's being presented.

Comment: I *think* if you switch to using keyframe animations you might be able to interact with the controls while they're 'in flight'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. I had this line at the end of the animation:

```
    [transitionContext completeTransition:YES];
```

No user interaction is allowed before the "completeTransition:YES" has been called.

Called it straight away and it works like a charm.

Comment: You should be careful about calling this before the animation is actually finished.  It lets UIKit know that the view controller transition is finished and you could cause instability by causing it before you're finished transitioning.